# how does custom comparator works exactly

Tags: c++, stdmap

Given `std::map< int, int, std::greater<int> > m;`

By default items that are inserted to maps are sorted in ascending order.
With the above definition I understand that we can change the sort order to descending.

I want to know how exactly custom comparator works. For example, when will this argument be checked, or where exactly in map implementation is this argument utilized?

Comment: Obviously the comparison is used every time you search an item directly or indirectly (for. ex. insertion). By the way, you cannot change the comparison dynamically nor change the key of already inserted items. If you do, you get undefined behavior which in a case like this will mainly prevent finding items or keep them properly sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map` associates **keys** with *values*. So, it consist of **key**/value pairs. In order to insert an new pair in the map or find an existing one, the program must be able to compare the **key** from the request with the **key**s which exist in the map. For this reason the comparators are used. The stl provides you with a few standard comparators, like `less`, `greater`, `less_equals`, `greater_equal`. They provide a common interface for 'map' to use and do `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=` operation on the pairs of **key**s. So, during the 'map' operations the comparator's `operator()` is called with 2 keys to compare them.

The default comparator is 'less'. So, in your case the comparator will return true if the first *int* **key** is less than the second *int* **key**. This would guarantee a particular order of insertion of the pairs in the map. If you explicitly use the 'greater' comparator, it will return 'false' in the case above and it will change the order in which elements are inserted.

You can also think about a sorted list or an array where the every previous element is `less` than the second. if you change your comarator for sorting to be `greater` the sorted array will be reversed.

You can create a custom comparator as well and do some different types of compare operations.

In general a custom comparator might be needed for simple types, like int, char *, ... If you use an object as a 'key' element, you can just overload the `operator<`, if the `less` comparator is in use.

Comment: Hi Serge, Thank you for answering my query. Now i'm clear about the calling. But one more question is operator() needs to be overloaded for Comparator. But at which point thi overloaded function is called?

Comment: @RandomGuy: `Comparator(key1, key2)` is called every time that two keys need to be compared.

Comment: Note that you have UB if you use `less_equal` or `greater_equal` in `map`, because of the [ordering requirements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) "For all a, comp(a,a)==false" and "If comp(a,b)==true then comp(b,a)==false"